# NCurses doesn't change colours, shows 16 colours only

Tags: ruby, windows, ncurses

I'm trying to get 256-colour support working for Curses and Ruby on Windows. I'm pretty sure it's possible, because Brogue uses curses, and has 256-colour support for Windows.

Right now, my setup is to use Ruby 1.8.7 (yech) with NCurses (0.9.1 pre-compiled binaries).

I see two problems right now, which I suspect are related:

- `Curses.colors` returns `16`
- `Curses.init_color(...)` doesn't error out, but doesn't do anything.

Some legwork:

- `ENV['TERM']` evaluates to `xterm-256color`
- Tried both Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0 (NCurses doesn't load)
- `can_change_color` returns `false`

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you targeting a standard Windows console window, e.g. cmd.exe?

Comment: @echristopherson yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows console window only supports 16 colors. You would have better luck with another console/terminal emulator like [mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/), [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), or [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Comment: Brogue pulls it off using, from what I can tell, NCurses. I don't think this is true.

Comment: Brogue implements its own terminal window using SDL.

Comment: Are you sure? I looked through `term.h` and saw raw curses calls like `init_color(...)`. Regardless, their terminal does not look like the Windows console, and the Windows console seems to be restricted to 16 colours as you suggested.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but I haven't dug too heavily into the code. I think it uses curses to be portable, and then has a terminal layer that curses talks to on Windows.

Comment: FYI, I tried all three, and none of these produce 256 colours.